# REST API to read folders in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, folder

I am able to get all root folders in a library using below API

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('"+foderUrl +"')/folders?$select=Name"
```

But I am not able to get what to use to get all root folders in a custom list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax will get the root folders in a list

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/list name')/folders
```

It will return folders you have created in a list and 2 additional folders "Item" and "Attachments" which come with SP List. We need to exclude these using query filters.